# How to get file names dynamically from azure data factory

Tags: azure, parameters, dataset, azure-data-factory

How to get one specific file dynamically from azure data factory.
I want only 1 file with same name with different folders.
I have a 3 folder(2022, 01, 01) having 3 files(File name:1.amazon_india_20220101.csv, 2.flipkart_India_20220101.csv, 3.jio_India_20220101.csv, i want only jio_India_20220101.csv file with date 01 folder, and next day 02 date folder with Jio_India_20220102.csv file

Comment: Can you provide what you have tried so far? any error/blockers?

Comment: I have a 3 folder(2022, 01, 01) having 3 files(File name:1.amazon_india_20220101.csv, 2.flipkart_India_20220101.csv, 3.jio_India_20220101.csv,      i want only jio_India_20220101.csv file, and

Comment: Please edit your question and show what you have tried so far? any error/ blockers that you faced?

Comment: Next day we received 3 files with 2022, 01, 02 folder with same names with date

Comment: Please check [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example - Help Center - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: how to create parameters for getting filename dynmically

Comment: Can you give your source folder structure hierarchy and expected output? How you are identifying target file? what is the filter condition for the required file here? Can you show your pipeline flow?

Comment: Source folder-- Sales/2022/01/01--- 3 files (File name:1.amazon_india_20220101.csv, 2.flipkart_India_20220101.csv, 3.jio_India_20220101.csv) 
And next day source folder--Sales/2022/01/02 ----3 files (File name:1.amazon_india_20220102.csv, 2.flipkart_India_20220102.csv, 3.jio_India_20220102.csv)

Comment: Above comment-- i want only Jio_India sales table, when i select date folder

Answer (score 0):

You can use Get Meta data activity and filter activity to achieve your requirement.

This is sample source folder structure:

Similarly, folders `02` and `01` were also created.

[image]

First give the wild card path holder `*/*/*` like below in the source dataset path.

[image]

Give the **Childitems** field list in the Get meta data activity.

[image]

This will list all the files in the folders structure. Then use filter activity with `@activity('Get Metadata1').output.childItems`  as **items** and `@and(startswith(item().name, 'jio_India'),endswith(item().name, '.csv'))` as condition.

[image]

This will give the Desired files list:

[image]